# is RTC proxy server only read only?

Tags: rtc, jazz, ibm-jazz

in RTC, for Global Software development scenario, there is the concept of cached proxies.
as i understand, it is only a read only proxy which will help while loading a component in the remote location.[scm part]
All Commit and Deliver actions when the changes are transmitted to the central server, the changes are sent directly over WAN. So these actions do not benefit from the proxy. Is this understanding correct?

Or does the proxy help in improving the performance for deliver/commit actions from the remote location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cache proxy are mentioned in:

- "[Does Rational Team Concert support MultiSite?](https://jazz.net/blog/index.php/2010/10/04/does-rational-team-concert-support-multisite/) "
- "[Using content caching proxies for Jazz Source Control](https://jazz.net/library/article/325)"

> We realize that there will still be cases where a WAN connection will not meet the 200ms guidance. In this case, we’ve leveraged the Web architecture of RTC to allow caching proxies to be used.
>   Based on standard Web caching technology, IBM or Apache HTTP Server or Squid, a cache can be deployed in the location which has a poor connection to the central server.
>   This caching proxy will cache SCM contents that are fetched from the server, greatly improving access times for the RTC client, and reducing traffic on the network.

So in case of RTC, it is more targeted to quicken "Load" and "Accept" and operations, rather than "Commit" and "Deliver".
If multiple developers all load from a specific stream, a caching proxy will help reduce the network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

We realize that there will still be cases where a WAN connection will not meet the 200ms guidance. In this case, we’ve leveraged the Web architecture of RTC to allow caching proxies to be used.
Based on standard Web caching technology, IBM or Apache HTTP Server or Squid, a cache can be deployed in the location which has a poor connection to the central server.
This caching proxy will cache SCM contents that are fetched from the server, greatly improving access times for the RTC client, and reducing traffic on the network.
So in case of RTC, it is more targeted to quicken "Load" and "Accept" and operations, rather than "Commit" and "Deliver".
If multiple developers all load from a specific stream, a caching proxy will help reduce the network traffic.